# how to not to give overlay for specific view

Tags: android, android-overlay

I have have an activity who have black transparent overlay.

What I need to do is remove overlay for specific button in an activity.But all other part extract button will consist of an overlay.

Comment: not clear about what you are asking..

Comment: Add a dummy button in front of overlay layout in exact same position of your actual button. Hide the transparent overlay and dummy button on click of Dummy button

Comment: did u asking like One button can overlay other one button

Comment: @ND1010_ No, I am asking there is black overlay dialog box and behind that there is an activity which consist of a button.I want to show that overlay dialog box as well as a button which is hide by overlay.So how to only show that button?

Comment: ok understand what you are asking about 
you have One activity in that activity having one button on click  of that button open a Dialogbox when Dialog box will open then it self and also  showing button that in activity right ?

Comment: HAlf right,Activity will open will an overlay of dialog box,But Activity will consist of button that i need to show on overlay

Answer (score 0):

You can add a view with black overlay. Use of RelativeLayout is a great solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
   <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Press Me"/>
   <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8000"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks.